# pymysql.err.OperationalError: (2006, "MySQL server has gone away (TimeoutError(110, 'Connection timed out'))")

Tags: python-3.x, flask, mysql-python, pymysql

My question is about reconnecting to MySQL server if any error encounters.

I am connecting to the MySQL server in Flask:

```
connection = pymysql.connect(host='host',
                             user='user',
                             connect_timeout= 31536000,
                             password='passwd',
                             db='db_name',
                             charset='utf8mb4',
                             cursorclass=pymysql.cursors.DictCursor)
```

and for the query using the cursor as well:
Flask route code:

```
@app.route("/chart", methods=['GET', 'POST'])
def chart():
    try:
        with connection.cursor() as cursor:
        #line chart open tickets
        query = "select createdDate,rootCause,requestId from db_name;"
        df = pd.read_sql(query, connection)
        print(df)

    except pymysql.MySQLError as e:
        print(e)
```

I want to reconnect to db when I get the error:

```
pymysql.err.OperationalError: (2006, "MySQL server has gone away (TimeoutError(110, 'Connection timed out'))")
```

Please help me find the solution for this error.

How to reconnect to the database when any error encounters.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks like you are using a single connection forever. Try to create a new connection every time and close it once the required queries are run.
This issue can be avoided through this.

Comment: This misses the point of connection pooling.

Answer (score 2):

Setting `pool_pre_ping=True` when calling `create_engine()` seems to have helped quite a bit in my case.

Example:

```
engine = create_engine(db_connection, pool_pre_ping=True)
```

From the [SQLAlchemy docs](https://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/14/core/engines.html#sqlalchemy.create_engine.params.pool_pre_ping) on `pool_pre_ping`:

"If True will enable the connection pool “pre-ping” feature that tests connections for liveness upon each checkout."